# Escaping single quote in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want PLSQL to generate strings like:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN TABLE.COLUMN IS 'comment from database';
```

My solution is:

```
declare
  str_comment varchar2(4000);
begin
  for rec in (select table_name, column_name, description from description_table)
  loop
    str_comment:='COMMENT ON COLUMN '||rec.table_name||'.'||rec.column_name||'  IS '''||rec.description||'''; ' ;
    dbms_output.put_line(str_comment);
  end loop;
end;
```

Output is OK when it doesn't contain single qoutes in `rec.description`. Otherwise there is need for escape letter. How should I implement it?

OK output line (It's has escape letter to preserve single qoute):

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN TABLE1.COLUMN1_LV  IS 'It''s secret';
```

NOT NOK output line because no escape letter for single quote added and doesn't compile:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN TABLE1.COLUMN1_LV  IS 'It's secret';
```

My solution is not to check if description contains single quotes. I just replace source (description) column's single quote by two single quotes before generating `COMMENT ON` strings and then I `ROLLBACK`.

Any better solution?

Comment: Replacing the single quote with a double one is fine. What's the point of `ROLLBACK`? Could you please post the whole code (with replace and rollback)?

Comment: @Quassnoi he probably updates the description_table, and then rollbacks the update

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I do this sort stuff a fair bit (usually generating insert/update statements).

You just need to use the replace function to turn all the `'` into `''`. i.e. Change it to:

```
str_comment:='COMMENT ON COLUMN '||rec.table_name||'.'||rec.column_name
            ||' IS '''||REPLACE( rec.description,'''','''''')||'''; ' ;
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the Quote operator like

```
str_comment:='COMMENT ON COLUMN '||rec.table_name||'.'||rec.column_name||' IS q''[' ||rec.description|| ']'';' ;
```

see http://psoug.org/reference/string_func.html

Comment: This will not work if the description itself contains `]'`.

Comment: But you can use other characters in place of [ and ].  In fact, anything other than space, RETURN or tab.

Comment: @mik I know this is an old comment, but for the benefit of anyone redirected to this answer, it's perfectly fine for the quoted string to contain the quotation character. For example, the following works perfectly well, at least in 11.2.0.4: `SELECT q'{{test}{from}}' FROM dual;` this returns: `{test}{from}`

Comment: @Boneist, but, as I wrote, it cannot contain `}'` (quotation character followed by an apostrophe)

Comment: @mik ah, good point. Clearly I need a new eyetest, as I somehow didn't see the `'`... d'oh!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `REPLACE` function in your select.

```
declare
str_comment varchar2(4000);
begin
for rec in (SELECT table_name, column_name, REPLACE(description, '''', '''''') 
                FROM description_table)
loop
str_comment:='COMMENT ON COLUMN ' || rec.table_name || '.' 
                 ||rec.column_name|| ' IS ''' ||rec.description|| '''; ' ;
dbms_output.put_line(str_comment);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: This will give `PLS-00302: component 'DESCRIPTION' must be declared`, because there is no `description` field in `rec`. You should either add a column alias after the `REPLACE()`, or put the `REPLACE` in the assignment to `str_comment` statement.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use '' in the code
But Before trying it to the actual code ,

try the line which has quotes in the dual

For example:

```
select '''sumesh''' from dual
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer is different from the accepted one.