# PL/SQL, how to escape single quote in a string?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the Oracle PL/SQL, how to escape single quote in a string ? I tried this way, it doesn't work.

```
declare
  stmt varchar2(2000);
begin
  for i in 1021 .. 6020
  loop
    stmt := 'insert into MY_TBL (Col) values(\'ER0002\')';

    dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
    execute immediate stmt;
    commit;
  end loop;
exception
  when others then
    rollback;
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping single quote in PLSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678478/escaping-single-quote-in-plsql)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can use literal quoting:

```
stmt := q'[insert into MY_TBL (Col) values('ER0002')]';
```

Documentation for literals [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref344).

Alternatively, you can use two quotes to denote a single quote:

```
stmt := 'insert into MY_TBL (Col) values(''ER0002'')';
```

The literal quoting mechanism with the Q syntax is more flexible and readable, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, using double single quotes was all i needed to escape the single quote.

Answer (score 38):

Here's [a blog post](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2195) that should help with escaping ticks in strings.

Here's the simplest method from said post:

> The most simple and most used way is to use a single quotation mark with two single quotation marks in both sides.
>
> `SELECT 'test single quote''' from dual;`
>
> The output of the above statement would be:
> test single quote'
>
> Simply stating you require an additional single quote character to print a single quote character. That is if you put two single quote characters Oracle will print one. The first one acts like an escape character.
>
> This is the simplest way to print single quotation marks in Oracle. But it will get complex when you have to print a set of quotation marks instead of just one. In this situation the following method works fine. But it requires some more typing labour.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to DCookie's answer above, you can also use chr(39) for a single quote.

I find this particularly useful when I have to create a number of insert/update  statements based on a large amount of existing data.

Here's a very quick example:

Lets say we have a very simple table, Customers, that has 2 columns, FirstName and LastName.  We need to move the data into Customers2, so we need to generate a bunch of INSERT statements.

```
Select 'INSERT INTO Customers2 (FirstName, LastName) ' ||
       'VALUES (' || chr(39) || FirstName || chr(39) ',' || 
       chr(39) || LastName || chr(39) || ');' From Customers;
```

I've found this to be very useful when moving data from one environment to another, or when rebuilding an environment quickly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I use  like this:

```
stmt := q'!insert into MY_TBL (Col) values('ER0002')!';
```

Adding: **q'!** before and **!'** after string.

This is another reference: [Alternative Quoting Mechanism (''Q'') for String Literals](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html)

Answer (score 0):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into MY_TBL (Col) values(''ER0002'')'`; worked for me.
closing the `varchar`/`string` with two pairs of single quotes did the trick. Other option could be to use `using` keyword, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into MY_TBL (Col) values(:text_string)' using 'ER0002'`; Remember `using` keyword will not work, if you are using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute DDL's with parameters, however, using quotes will work for DDL's.