# Is there a way to quote SQL strings containing apostrophes in Oracle to avoid needing to escape the apostrophe?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, escaping

I write a lot of dynamic SQL in PL/SQL of the kind:

```
-- Let's assume the query is much more complex and bind variables are not a solution here
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO foo (col) VALUES (''somevalue'')';
```

Observe the nasty escaping duplication of apostrophes to form valid SQL / PL/SQL syntax. Is there any way I can quote the SQL string literal such that I no longer have to escape? This would be great to copy paste the SQL string from an actual execution into a PL/SQL program, without tedious patching of apostrophes.

(I asked this question here deliberately to document the quoting feature with my own answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a little known feature since Oracle 10g called "quoting string literals". You can write:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[INSERT INTO foo (col) VALUES ('somevalue')]';
```

The price you pay is that your string literal can no longer contain `]` because that's now a part of the string termination token. Possible characters to use in this way are:

- `q'! ... !'`
- `q'[ ... ]'`
- `q'{ ... }'`
- `q'( ... )'`
- `q'< ... >'`

#### More information:

- [A blog post that explains it in more detail](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311)
- [A livesql script by Steven Feuerstein illustrating it in action](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html)
- [The official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)
- [An answer to this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315369/521799)