# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis with a SQL Statement in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

When running the below query getting the above error,

```
String sql = "((NAME= '" + sReceipts[0] + "' ) OR (SECTION IN ('RECEIPT', 'PROJECT') AND NAME IS NULL))";
```

`sReceipts[0]` value is 'Tom's' (with an **APOSTROPHE**) gives the **error**

But if sReceipts[0] = 'Ann' **no error** occur.

Tried to solve with String.Format but I couldn't.
What is the best approach please?

Answer (score 4):

You should use parameterised queries such as the below:

```
OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT YourColumn FROM 
YourTable WHERE ((NAME= :receiptName ) OR (SECTION IN ('RECEIPT', 'PROJECT') AND NAME IS NULL))", db);
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("recieptName", sReceipts[0]));
```

See [MSDN OracleCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using the Microsoft class and [OracleParameterCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm) for the equivalent Oracle parameter collection.

Answer (score -2):

I would wrap sReceipts[0] in a regular expression that replaces the apostrophe with two apostrophes.

[Escaping single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string)

[Oracle regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Comment: No, manually escaping is *extremely* error-prone. Parameterized queries are the way forward here.