# oracle column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I got this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at line 14
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

here is the code. I copy and paste the field name (all in cap). The field name should be correct

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  my_creation_dt date;
  mysql varchar2(6000) := '';
BEGIN
  select creation_dt into my_creation_dt from role_table where security_role = 'admin';

  mysql := 'insert into role_grant_table (PERSON_ID, CREATION_DT, SECURITY_ROLE, 
    SSS_CREATE_DT, UPDATE_WHO, UPDATE_ON) values (1234, SYSDATE, 
    "ADMIN", 
    :my_creation_dt, 
    "myname", 
    SYSDATE)'; -- line 14, column not allowed here

  execute immediate mysql using (my_creation_dt);

END;
```

Comment: by the way - for future reference: "line 14" is pointing you to the `execute immediate` statement, which is where the exception is actually being raised at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-quotes are used to enclose identifiers (usually when they have mixed case or punctuation characters).  So Oracle is interpreting `"ADMIN"` and `"myname"` as identifiers, which in this context the parser takes to be column names.  The error is telling you that referencing a column here is not allowed.

Presumably, you intended those to be the string values to be inserted.  Use 
single-quotes to enclose string literals, i.e. `'ADMIN'` and `'myname'`.

Comment: OK, since you are building the dynamic SQL statement as a string itself, you do need to escape those single quotes.  But that requires two single-quote characters, not one double-quote character.  Copying and pasting your text, it appears you have double-quote characters.

Comment: Yes, this is how to escape single quote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string