# Expression Replace in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to perform an UPDATE on the database, but within that update there is a section that has ' ' (single quotes), because of these quotes when running the error script, can anyone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRCLg.png)

I've been on this stress all afternoon

Comment: Welcome! "_I've been on this stress all afternoon_" Note: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/11107541) (just in case you were hoping to get an answer very quickly). See also [/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Could you please [read about why 'Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) and [edit] to apply what you learn to ask your question? You can also see [ask] for further guidance. For example, a better question might look like: "_What is the cause of <specific issue>, and how can the problem be resolved to get <specific correct behaviour>?_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 single quotes for that :

```
update galaxy
set sun = replace(sun, 'font ''Arial''', 'font ''Arial'' 12px')
where earth = 148;
```

see: [PL/SQL, how to escape single quote in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string)