# SQL trigger replacing " with ' quotes

Tags: sql, plsql, dbeaver

I have a procedure that passes in a script:

```
        sql_str := 'CREATE TABLE '|| temp_table_name || ' NOLOGGING COMPRESS PARALLEL (DEGREE 8 INSTANCES 1) as '||
    '  Select DISTINCT           '||
    '  /*+ driving_table(CT)     '||
    '   FULL(CT) PARALLEL (CT, 8)  */  '||
    '   TO_CHAR(N.SRV_DT, "YYYY") AS SERV_YR        '||
    '   ,TO_CHAR(N.SRV_DT, "YYYYMM") AS SERV_YRMO  '||
    '   ,CT.TCN      '||
    '   ,CT.CLAIM_CNTR '||
    '   ,CASE WHEN CT.CLAIM_TRANS_SRC_CD IN ("C") THEN "FFS"  '||
    '       WHEN CT.CLAIM_TRANS_SRC_CD IN ("E") THEN "MCO"   END AS FFS_MCO   '||  
    ' FROM table X  ' :
```

However when I

```
sql_str := replace(sql_str,'"','''');
```

Then

```
EXEC_CMD (sql_str, '  CREATED TABLE ' || temp_table_name || ' ', err_fatal);
```

The output fails because in random places there are " quotes as you can see in the CT.CLAIM_CNTR

```
    TO_CHAR(N.SRV_DT,
'YYYY') AS SERV_YR
    , TO_CHAR(N.SRV_DT, 'YYYYMM') AS SERV_YRMO
    , CT.TCN
    , CT.CLAIM_CNTR"   
    ,CASE WHEN CT.CLAIM_TRANS_SRC_CD IN ('C') THEN 'FFS'        
    WHEN CT.CLAIM_TRANS_SRC_CD IN ('E') THEN""  'MCO'   END AS FFS_MCO
```

I am using DBeaver as the compiler. Not sure if anyone has seen or knows how to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL, how to escape single quote in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string)

Comment: No idea. Sorry. The code looks fine and works of course (https://dbfiddle.uk/SQT6IVwD).

Comment: unfortunately converting all to " to '' and removing the conversion string does nothing.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea from step 1. Creating an actual temp table from a select query is rarely the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use the q-quoting mechanism? It lets you use single quotes *normally*, without *escaping* them or using (and replacing) double quotes or whatever else you might be doing.

Code you posted wouldn't work anyway as it references the `ct` table which doesn't exist in `from` clause, but I presume that it is not the issue here.

So:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    temp_table_name varchar2(20) := 'test_1';
  3    sql_str         varchar2(4000);
  4  begin
  5    sql_str := 'create table ' || temp_table_name || chr(10) ||
  6      ' nologging compress parallel (degree 8 instances 1) as ' ||
  7      q'[select distinct /*+ driving_table(ct) full(ct) paralleetl (ct, 8) */
  8  to_char(n.srv_dt, 'yyyy') as serv_yr,
  9  to_char(n.srv_dt, 'yyyymm') as serv_yrmo,
 10  ct.tcn,
 11  ct.claim_cntr,
 12  case when ct.claim_trans_src_cd in ('C') then 'FFS'
 13       when ct.claim_trans_src_cd in ('E') then 'MCO'
 14  end as ffs_mco
 15  from table x]';
 16    dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
 17  end;
 18  /
create table test_1
 nologging compress parallel (degree 8 instances 1) as select distinct /*+ driving_table(ct) full(ct) paralleetl (ct, 8) */
to_char(n.srv_dt, 'yyyy') as serv_yr,
to_char(n.srv_dt, 'yyyymm') as serv_yrmo,
ct.tcn,
ct.claim_cntr,
case when ct.claim_trans_src_cd in ('C') then 'FFS'

when ct.claim_trans_src_cd in ('E') then 'MCO'
end as ffs_mco
from table x

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```