# Inserting string with special characters into a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

How can I successfully run such a query in SqlDeveloper?

```
execute immediate q'#
                    insert into results(SrcProcedure) 
                                values('d/&'s*73;.f45')
                    #';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping single quote in PLSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678478/escaping-single-quote-in-plsql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which "special" characters are allowed in SQL Server varchar fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038213/which-special-characters-are-allowed-in-sql-server-varchar-fields)

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn the escaping rules for your language. In SQL, `'` is a special character. The escape for it is `''`:

```
execute immediate q'#
                insert into results(SrcProcedure) 
                            values(''d/&''''s*73;.f45'')
                #';
```

Rule: For each level of nesting, you need to duplicate all single quotes.

```
d/&'s*73;.f45
'd/&''s*73;.f45'
...values(''d/&''''s*73;.f45'')...
```

You can get away with less quotes if you [use `q'{...}'`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm):

```
execute immediate q'{
                insert into results(SrcProcedure) 
                            values('d/&''s*73;.f45')
                }';
```

Related:

- [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)
- http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm

Comment: The alternative quoting syntax works with almost any character as the quote_delimiter.  `q'# ... #';` works fine.  The problem is that the string inside the string, inside the string must be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to insert the value `d/&'s*73;.f45` and the `'` character is interpreted as the end of the value.

You need to escape the `'` character:

```
execute immediate q'#
                insert into results(SrcProcedure) 
                            values('d/&''s*73;.f45')
                #';
```

Or you can nest the alternative quoting mechanism to avoid any string escaping:

```
execute immediate q'#
                insert into results(SrcProcedure) 
                            values(q'!d/&'s*73;.f45!')
                #';
```