# Single quote in execute immediate variable - Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure which has:

```
execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(S_NM) FROM '||lc_s_d_tb_nm||' WHERE S_NM IN('''||in_s_nm||''') AND '||lc_s_t_col||'='''||in_s_type||''' ' into lc_s_count;
```

The parameter in_s_nm is being sent by another function and one of the value is - `Test - Mother's Identifier`

Because of `'` (apostrophe), my sql is not working.

How can I fix it so it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping single quote in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678478/escaping-single-quote-in-plsql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop right there.. Don't  use, I repeat, **don't ever use concatenation** of values in a dynamic SQL ( except for Table and column names  or for educational purposes :-; ). It is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and it could become a security threat.

Your query should be rewritten as

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(S_NM) FROM '||lc_s_d_tb_nm||' 
   WHERE S_NM = :s_nm
AND '||lc_s_t_col||'= :s_type'  into lc_s_count  USING in_s_nm,in_s_type;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1e6ce8aa261c457e9010cf2500933a18)

Comment: It could only be that you want to use SQL Injection as tool, where it makes sense to use concatenation. BTW you can also chance `WHERE S_NM IN (:s_nm)` to `WHERE S_NM = :s_nm` - that's what got me confused a little at first, cause i thought you wanted to pass multiple values to the dynamic sql.

Comment: It's been removed as well. I should familiarize myself more in using the SO mobile app:

Answer (score 1):

Just use `replace(in_s_nm, '''', '''''')` instead of `in_s_nm`.

Answer (score 0):

In 10g Oracle introduced the [Quote Operator](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html) as an alternative or rather an extension that eliminates, at least most if not all, of that double quotation problem. For example try:

```
select q'/this is a single quote ', and this a double '' and even a triple '''/' from dual
union all 
select 'this is a single quote '', and this a double '''' and even a triple ''''''' from dual;
```

I think you'll find the first much easier to deal with than the second although they produce the same result.